# 'Frame' or "frames' of reference

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, orthography

I am stuck on whether to use 'frame' or 'frames' of reference.

Example sentences:

This study seeks to add value to the theologies of the Hebrew Scriptures in both its Hebrew and Greek frame/frames of reference.

and

... exploring beliefs and ideologies when reference is made to the Divine in both its Hebrew and Greek conceptual frame/frames of reference.

Comment: Do you consider them to be the same frame of reference?

Comment: They are both conceptual frames of reference.

Except one is Hebrew and the other is Greek. 

So they are and they aren't the same.

Comment: That seems to be a central problem in theology; we're not going to solve it grammatically.

Comment: Grammatical number is more concrete than that. If you consider them to be a (single) shared frame of reference, use the singular. If you are treating them as different frames of reference, use the plural. If you consider them to be the same frame of reference just because they are both conceptual frames of reference, then you would have to consider Arabic, Chinese and other frames of reference to be the same as well because they are all conceptual frames of reference. If that’s the case, use the singular. If you want to talk about them with their individual idiosyncrasies, use the plural.

Comment: Thank you as always for your insightful comments - this site is always a life-saver for me!

Comment: If we assume a single *Hebrew and Greek frame,* then the word "both" seems to serve no sensible function.

Answer (score 0):

The advice that has been given in the comments is applicable on condition that your readers are sure to know beforehand that  there can be only one frame of reference for each culture. Otherwise, if they are not familiar with the idea and if these terms appear at the outset of your work, they will have to wait further reading so as to be certain of what is meant.

- This study seeks to add value to the theologies of the Hebrew Scriptures in both its Hebrew and Greek frames of reference.

The above sentence does not exclude the possibility of several frames in Hebrew and several frames in Greek. The following does.

- This study seeks to add value to the theologies of the Hebrew Scriptures in both its Hebrew frame of reference and its Greek frame of reference.

In case this is a new concept for the reader, and for the first mention of it, at least, it is preferable to write that the long way.

Comment: Excellent feedback. Thank you!

Comment: But, as Gary Botnovcan almost said in a comment above, the use of "both" separates the Greek and Hebrew frames of reference into two different entities. Without "both" you can regard them as a single frame of reference. If you do that you use the singular form of the noun. The form of the noun actually defines whether you consider the frame(s) of reference to be singular or plural. You can't use 'both' and the singular form of the verb, they contradict each other.

Comment: Good points! For my context, I am going to opt for the plural usage. Thank you!